# Where can I find the checkout page form field in Magento 2.0.1?

Tags: php, magento

I am very new in Magento.

Now I have website where I want to change the form field position from the checkout page form. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here you can see the location of each section but I can't find the form field to that location. I want to move the country before the city field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit on the lay out file of one page checkout "checkout_index_index.xml "
Please checko out this ref : -

[Go To](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139557/magento-2-change-the-order-of-the-shipping-fields-on-the-checkout-page)